# javascript form verification

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="masterform type-selection">


<div class="radio"><span><input type="radio" name="feature_value_6" value="10" required=""></span></div><label>Cool</label>



function ShowLoading() {

var verif = true;

$(".masterform input").each(function() {
if($(this).val() == ""){
verif = false;
}
});
var radio = false;
$(".type-selection div.radio span").each(function() {
if($('.masterform input[type=radio]:checked').size() > 0){
radio = true;
}
});

if(verif == true && radio == true){
window.loading_screen = window.pleaseWait({
blabla }); }

}
```

i tried everything , the variable send me true but when i use this verification on radio input nothing work. my function work only when i stop the submit on my form by clicking on the cross of my safari navigator !

Everything works fine on chrome but cant make it work on safari

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code. Looks like you just need to use `length` instead of `$.size()`

```js
var radio = false;
$(".type-selection div.radio span").each(function() {
  if ($('.masterform input[type=radio]:checked').length > 0) {
    radio = true;
  }
  console.log(radio);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masterform type-selection">
  <div class="radio">
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="feature_value_6" value="10" required="" checked>
    </span>
  </div>
  <label>Cool</label>
</div>
```

Comment: just tried same thing not working until i stop the page charge by cross on navigator

Comment: @jolo "page charge"? What does that mean?

Comment: when the page is loading

Comment: @jolo you need to be more specific and give more context. I don't know what you're talking about. Give us a working demo that shows the problem clearly.

Comment: my function is called onSubmit form ! it work perfectly on chrome but on safari it work only when i stop the loading on the page by click the cross of the navigator :/

Comment: @jolo **Give us a working demo that shows the problem clearly.**

Comment: how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "prop" property of jQuery, like this:

```
$(".type-selection div.radio span input[type='radio']").each(function(elemIndex, domElement) { //Each radio 
    if($(domElement).prop('checked')){
        radio = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: just tried same thing not working until i stop the page charge by cross on navigator ! its so weird everything work fine without that radio check